# Resolve-DnsName : The term 'Resolve-DnsName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: shell-script, scripting, mono, .net, powershell

Why is `Resolve-DnsName` not recognized for `PowerShell Core`?  So far as I recall it works fine with `PowerShell` itself.

Is this a `.NET` versus `dotnet` problem?  That `dotnet` simply doesn't have this functionality?

```
thufir@dur:~/powershell/webservicex$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell/webservicex$ dotnet --version
2.1.4
thufir@dur:~/powershell/webservicex$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell/webservicex$ ./dns.ps1 
Resolve-DnsName : The term 'Resolve-DnsName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At /home/thufir/powershell/webservicex/dns.ps1:3 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName -Name localhost -Type ANY | Format-Table -AutoSize
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Resolve-DnsName:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

thufir@dur:~/powershell/webservicex$ 
thufir@dur:~/powershell/webservicex$ cat dns.ps1 
#!/usr/bin/pwsh -Command

Resolve-DnsName -Name localhost -Type ANY | Format-Table -AutoSize

thufir@dur:~/powershell/webservicex$
```

see closed question [also](https://askubuntu.com/q/1007058/45156), and [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f1654ffa-4c3e-4c02-be7f-58ab36e905a9/resolvednsname-cmdlet-missing?forum=WinServerPreview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [What's New In PowerShell Core 6.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-6) documentation, in the "Backwards Compatibility" section:

> Most of the modules that ship as part of Windows (for example,
>   DnsClient, Hyper-V, NetTCPIP, Storage, etc.) and other Microsoft
>   products including Azure and Office have not been explicitly ported to
>   .NET Core yet. The PowerShell team is working with these product
>   groups and teams to validate and port their existing modules to
>   PowerShell Core. With .NET Standard and CDXML, many of these
>   traditional Windows PowerShell modules do seem to work in PowerShell
>   Core, but they have not been formally validated, and they are not
>   formally supported.

While Powershell Core is GA, it is still very much a work in progress.

Answer (score 3):

There is a cross-platform module called `DnsClient-PS`, and the name of the command in that module is `Resolve-Dns`.  It functions a bit differently from `Resolve-DnsName`:

```
> Find-Module -Name PowerShellGet | Install-Module
> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted              https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

> Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Trusted              https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

> Install-Module -Name DnsClient-PS
> Resolve-Dns google.com | Select-Object -Expand Answers

DomainName  TimeToLive RecordClass RecordType RecordData
----------  ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
google.com. 401        IN          A          64.233.185.102
google.com. 401        IN          A          64.233.185.139
google.com. 401        IN          A          64.233.185.138
google.com. 401        IN          A          64.233.185.113
google.com. 401        IN          A          64.233.185.101
google.com. 401        IN          A          64.233.185.100
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the cmdlet `Resolve-DnsName` to work in PS 6 you must first import it or install it.

You can first try `Install-Module -Name DnsClient`.  It will use your default package manager to pull it down from the psgallery and install it.

Then, `Import-Module -Name "DnsClient"` to pull it in.

You `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet should then function.

You can also you use the various parameters of `Test-NetConnection` to resolve within the NetTCPIP module as well.